# Include shared library .so in gem file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shared-libraries

I have application in ruby which is using native extension made by my. It's linking to shared so library which cannot by installed automatically (it's distributed only as file). The question is, how can I add it to my gem file to be sure that my ruby native extension will be able to use it after gem install? This solution is made only for single architecture so I can use single so file for this purpose. As I understand, link to file in my `ext` directory should be passed somehow into makefile?

During development I've added path to my library using `ldconfig`, but right now I want to have "all in one solution" with simple installation. Sources for this library are not available so I have to use precompiled so library.

EDIT:

```
require 'mkmf'
THIS_DIR = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
NATIVE_DIR = File.join(THIS_DIR, 'native')
puts NATIVE_DIR
$LDFLAGS += " -L" + NATIVE_DIR + " -lmylibshared "
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH = NATIVE_DIR
create_makefile('myextension')
```

I've done something like that. It's working but only when I do exeute:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/so/library
```

As I suppose I can add this path manually to environment variable for my rails applications. But I want to make it as simple as possible. Is it any way to workaround this?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you have access to compile the source code, but I have a gem that used to connect to a precompiled shared object https://github.com/t12nslookup/advantage using "require_relative" ... (Now compiles the source code as it works) ... That code links to an existing shared library.

Comment: Thx for your answer but I don't understand how can I use it. My native extension is build from sources and working properly from ruby code. Issue is with that my native extension is looking for shared library... I'm looking for any option to not do manual lib installation step.

Comment: Ok I've solved it by adding rpath to ldflags, now it's ok :)